# Remove Space After a Particular Character in String

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have an string which is coming from a server :

```
<p>Test iOS Contact &nbsp;<a href=\"tel:(945) 369-8563\">(945) 369-8563</a></p>
```

I want to remove any space after tel which comes up to 10 characters in the phone number.

I am using the below code for that.

```
    if ([serviceMessage containsString:@"tel:"]) {
                NSUInteger location = [serviceMessage rangeOfString:@"tel:"].location + 4;
    serviceMessage = [serviceMessage substringFromIndex:location];
    [serviceMessage substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(11,0)];
    serviceMessage =[serviceMessage substringToIndex:10];
    NSLog(@"New Trimed string:%@",serviceMessage);
    serviceMessage = [serviceMessage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"Final Trimed string:%@",serviceMessage);
                                        }
```

Comment: could not able to understand you question. Plz explain ?

Comment: from the above string I want to remove the space within the phone number only

Comment: kindly share end result

Comment: in end result only I am getting is 9453698563, while I am needing of full string without the space between phone number only

Comment: is this what you want "<p>Test iOS Contact &nbsp;<a href="tel(945)369-8563">(945)369-8563</a></p>" ???

Comment: yes @AbdulRehmanWarraich

Answer (score 0):

There is code to do this

```
 NSString * serviceMessage = @"<p>Test iOS Contact &nbsp;<a href=\"tel:(945) 369-8563\">(945) 369-8563</a></p>";
NSArray *arr = [serviceMessage componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

NSString * newStr = [[arr objectAtIndex:1] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
NSString * updatedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[arr firstObject],newStr];
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: @Aditya Pandey is it helped?

Comment: @DharmbirSingh  I did not seen yours.

Comment: How could I know that ? I didn't.

Comment: @AbdulRehmanWarraich, no it is not helping, I have to remove the spaces only between first 10 numbers.

Comment: If you know how to code then this is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSString *)removeSpacseFromPhoneNumber:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *resultString = @"";
    NSString *phoneIndicatorString = @"tel:";

    NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:phoneIndicatorString];
    if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
        NSLog(@"String does not contain tel:");
        return nil;
    }

    resultString = [string substringToIndex:range.location + phoneIndicatorString.length]; // copy up to and including tel:
    NSString *phoneString = [string substringFromIndex:range.location + phoneIndicatorString.length + 1]; // copy from after tel:
    NSString * convertedPhoneString = [phoneString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    return [resultString stringByAppendingString:convertedPhoneString];
}
```

You can call this with:

```
NSString *result = [self removeSpacseFromPhoneNumber:yourString];
```

Comment: Hi @vincent if tel: is there two times with different phone numbers then what should I do?

Comment: If the phone number is in 2 string, just call the routine twice. The routine now search for tel: all space after that position (range.location) are removed. So also the double phone numbers from your example are handled correctly.

Comment: Hi @vincent it is removing space from complete string, while I have to remove space, only first 10 numbers, which comes after @"tel:"